# Normalization of samples before applying the t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, normalization

I am working on an algorithm for recommender systems. I want to compare its results to another method. For this purpose, I need to apply a t-test on their results to see if there's a significant difference between them. Each sample consists of 27 float numbers, and none of the samples has a normal distribution. After examining different statistical tests, I found the paired t-test more suitable. (there are about 6 ties in each experiment between the samples and samples are small, so I thought maybe Wilcoxon test can't be trusted.)
My question is that can I make samples' distribution normal to meet the neccessary assumptions of t-test? Is it correct to do so? if yes, please guide me how to do it?

Comment: What does "6 ties" mean: equal between the samples or equal within one of the  samples?  The former could suggest these are not independent while the latter could suggest they do not come from a continuous distribution

Comment: @Henry it means equal between the samples (an equal pair). No they are independant. Ties here means that in that speacial case there was no improvement and the results of the two methods are equal in that case

Comment: You refer to "samples" as if there might be more than two, in which case applying t-tests to all pairs of samples is problematic.  It would help us to know a little more about your situation.  As far as the Normality question goes, that has been asked and answered in (literally) hundreds of situations here on CV: please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=t+test+normal+distribution+score%3A5+is%3Aanswer).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, I don't quite understand the logic in the question.

But to answer the (first) question, inverse normal scores transformation can coerce a vector of numbers to a nearly normal distribution.  There are different variants of this transformation: including Elfving, Blom, van der Waerden, Tukey, and rankit.

This is related to the van der Waerden normal scores test.

But note that if you transform each sample individually, you would end up with samples with a similar distribution.

Comment: Wouldn't this make the objective of testing for a "significant difference" impossible?

Comment: If you transform each group separately, yes, you end up with groups with similar distributions (essentially a standard normal distribution, with mean of 0 and sd of 1).  So, testing the difference in the groups isn't helpful. ...  But the idea is to transform the entirety of the dependent variable, analogous to how the Kruskal-Wallis test applies a rank transformation to the entirety of the dependent variable.

Comment: So, also, with this approach, there's no guarantee that the distributions of individual groups would be normal, nor that the residuals from the analysis would be normal.

Comment: My point is that after the transformation, the t-test is not a comparison of the original arithmetic means: it's a different test than intended.  If the transformations of the groups are sufficiently strong, this can make a big difference.

Comment: Right.  I should have stated that a hypothesis test on any transformed data cannot be interpreted as a test on the original data.